# Creating a csv header independent of the csv data in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, reporting

I am attempting to programmatically create a csv header that contains some information about the report, for a program that will automatically generate reports using python. The header would ideally look something like this:

[image: csv header]

I have not found a good way to do this in python that is not easily replicable for other report types.

I have tried using the csv library to write a header, but i have achieved limited control of the resulting layout.

Comment: That looks like Excel output, not CSV.

Comment: You can't do this with CSV. It doesn't have any way to specify that a field should cover multiple columns, like `colspan` in HTML tables.

Comment: As the name indicates, it's just a set of column-separated values, there's no higher structure to it.

Comment: You can use `pyxl` to create an Excel spreadsheet. If Excel provides a way to do this, then I assume pyxl can do it as well.

Comment: A CSV header is a delimited list of column names. After which there are rows of delimited data. That is a CSV file. If you want meta-data you will need to put it somewhere else. You could create your own 'file format' with the meta-data, but you would need to also create the mechanism to unpack it into the meta-data and CSV parts.